# How to populate Contacts from Phone to Custom Listview?

Tags: android, database, contacts, custom-lists

I created a Custom ListView using `BaseAdapter` now I want to populate this Listview with Contact Name and Number from Phone book..I am trying this..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Rabtaye extends Activity {

    ListView msgList;
    ArrayList<MessageDetails> details;
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;

    Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        msgList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MessageList);
        details = new ArrayList<MessageDetails>();

        MessageDetails Detail = new MessageDetails();
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String info[] = { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID };
         for(String a:info){
         Detail.setName(a);
         }
         Detail.setNumber("0313");
         details.add(Detail);
//      int to[] = { R.id.name, R.id.number };
//      ListAdapter cursada = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
//              android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, cursor, info,
//              to);
        msgList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(details, this));


        msgList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                TextView s = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.name);
                String abc = s.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(Rabtaye.this, abc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I used different ways, but I am not able to populate ListView with Contact Name or Number. In this code I have to statically add name and number...I am quite confuse here..little help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance. I am newbie so please go easy on me..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. You're on the right track, but I think you're wandering a bit.

A ListView is a view object, not a BaseAdapter. As far as I can tell from your code, you don't need a custom adapter for your ListView.

What you should do is bind a regular CursorAdapter to your ListView, load the Contacts data you want from the Contacts Provider using a CursorLoader, then move the resulting Cursor to the CursorAdapter.

You can find the instructions for doing this in this Android training class:
[Loading Data in the Background](http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html).

What do you want in your custom ListView that you can't get from ListView itself?

Comment: the thing is that, I want to populate whole listview with all the contacts and have checkboxes with them. I tried default ListView but it doesnt show Numbers. That's why I switched to Custom Listview.

Answer (score 1):

If you're putting more than just a single list of items into a ListView (it looks like you're doing name, number, etc.) you have to create your own custom adapter. Extend the [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) class either in your activity, or in a new class. Then you'll have to override the `getView()` method. This is what is called every time a new item gets inflated.

You pass your `ArrayList` into the `BaseAdapter` when you create it. The `getView()` method of the adapter is where you code your logic to take the data and present it as a list item. You'll have to define a new XML file as a layout for each list item that contains your `TextViews` and whatnot for your different children in each list item, and that's what you populate with your data.

There are a bunch of examples all over if you search for "baseadapter". Here's [one](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/) that gives a pretty good intro.